# script_score the script could not be loaded scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently I use the Elastisearch 1.5.
I want to update to the Elasticsearch 1.7.

And then when I run below query to the ES1.7, I got the error which is

> nested: QueryParsingException[[my_index] script_score the script could not be
>   loaded]; nested: ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation
>   [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled];
>   .

This query definitely works on the ES 1.5 environment.
I want to use same query to the ES 1.7.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "fields": [
                "itemname"
              ],
              "query": "coke"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "script_score": {
        "script": "_score + doc['myscore'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have already read this document.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting

So, I have added below options to my elasticsearch.yml.

```
script.inline: on  
script.indexed: on 
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
```

And I did to restart elasticsearch daemon and to create index again, but I still got the error.

Does anyone advise me how can I solve this problem ?

Added

```
[root@elasticsearch]# curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Ghost Girl",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.1",
    "build_hash" : "b88f43fc40b0bcd7f173a1f9ee2e97816de80b19",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-07-29T09:54:16Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

[root@elasticsearch]# tail -n 10 /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
# http server. With this enabled, it may pose a security risk, so disabling
# it unless you need it is recommended (it is disabled by default).
#
#http.jsonp.enable: true

script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
script.search: on
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on

[root@elasticsearch]# /etc/rc.d/init.d/elasticsearch restart
Stopping elasticsearch:                                    [  OK  ]
Starting elasticsearch:                                    [  OK  ]

[root@elasticsearch]# curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty' -d '{
>   "query": {
>     "function_score": {
>       "query": {
>         "filtered": {
>           "query": {
>             "query_string": {
>               "fields": [
>                 "itemname"
>               ],
>               "query": "coke"
>             }
>           }
>         }
>       },
>       "script_score": {
>         "script": "_score * 0.5"
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }'
{
  "took" : 3029,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 3,
    "failed" : 2,
    "failures" : [ {
      "index" : "my_index",
      "shard" : 1,
      "status" : 400,
      "reason" : "RemoteTransportException[[Fury][inet[/xx.xx.xx.xx:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[ss][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n  \"query\": {\n    \"function_score\": {\n      \"query\": {\n        \"filtered\": {\n          \"query\": {\n            \"query_string\": {\n              \"fields\": [\n                \"itemname\"\n              ],\n              \"query\": \"coke\"\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      },\n      \"script_score\": {\n        \"script\": \"_score * 0.5\"\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[my_index] script_score the script could not be loaded]; nested: ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled]; "
    }, {
      "index" : "my_index",
      "shard" : 4,
      "status" : 400,
      "reason" : "RemoteTransportException[[Fury][inet[/xx.xx.xx.xx:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[my_index][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n  \"query\": {\n    \"function_score\": {\n      \"query\": {\n        \"filtered\": {\n          \"query\": {\n            \"query_string\": {\n              \"fields\": [\n                \"itemname\"\n              ],\n              \"query\": \"coke\"\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      },\n      \"script_score\": {\n        \"script\": \"_score * 0.5\"\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[my_index] script_score the script could not be loaded]; nested: ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled]; "
    } ]
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add `script.search: on` and `script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true`?

Comment: @Val Thanks, I added those parameters. but it does't work. currently I have added "script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true" and "script.inline: on" and
"script.indexed: on" and "script.search: on" and "script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on". Any ideas ?

Comment: Weird, the exact same query with the exact same settings work perfectly on my 1.7. Are you sure you've restarted your ES cluster?

Comment: @Val Yeah, I'm sure I have restarted the ES. I added the command on the question. Is there any different on your environment ? I changed the "script_score" more simple.

Comment: Are you sure that your launch script in `init.d` takes the correct `elasticsearch.yml` config file into account? Do you have several ES installed?

Comment: @Val Yes, the init.d script indicates  the elasticsearch.yml. # cat /etc/rc.d/init.d/elasticsearch | grep "/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml"
CONF_FILE="/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml" And the server has only one ES which is 1.7.1. I installed it using yum command.

Comment: I have rebuild new server and then it works. It might have old module or something like that in the previous server. Thank you @Val

Comment: Ok, glad I could help figure it out.

Comment: Hello i am getting same error and i am using 1.7.1 elasticsearch in windows, my yml file is in inside conf folder can you please tell me what code should i write and where inside my yml file coz everything inside the file is written as # or ## i dont know where to put the lines please help me i am struggling from ariund 2 weeks for this problem ????

Comment: @Sudhanshu Gaur Hello, in this case my elasticsearch.yml is almost default. I added few settings last of this file. pls see it. https://gist.github.com/k1row/3c1b6f9d255362153a21

Comment: thanx a lot for sharing that @k16

Answer (score 6):

add `script.engine.groovy.inline.update: on` to the .yml file

Answer (score 0):

As the repond said :`nested: ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled]`

You may add `script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on` in `.yml` file.

Comment: please also provide an example based on OPs post